# how to handle table lock or query queue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions, queue

I got some duplicated row in my table but its impossible to insert via http request because I have validations for user balance that will change by every request and a request must be accepted by admin before another request. In this case The user had a balance of USD 1000. According to my code he can request once for USD 1000. but all of a sudden I got two rows at the same time in my database. how it may happen and what is the solution of this problem?

> > what I assume is when the 1st request arrived, the `withdraw` table was locked due to some other calculation so the balance was unchanged and the query was queued, as user got no response due to table lock he requested again then both requests were inserted!

> > please be informed that this is not happening everyday. It happens very rarely like 1 or 2 duplicate request in a year

```
    public function withdrawBalance(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->api_key == ApiKey()) {

            $userInfo = User::find($request->user_id);

            $checkPendingRequest = Withdraw::where(['user_id' => $request->user_id, 'status' => 0])->get(); //status column have default 0 until admin approval

            if (count($checkPendingRequest) > 0) {
                return response()->json(['status' => false, 'action' => 'already_pending_one', 'message' => 'Already have a pending request!.']);
            }

            $gs = GeneralSetting::first();
            $balance = HoldingBalance($request->user_id)['withdrawble_balance'];


            if ($request->amount > $balance) {
                return response()->json(['status' => false, 'action' => 'insufficiant_balance', 'message' => 'Insufficient amount!.']);
            }


            if ($request->withdraw_method == 'bkash') {
                $method_name = 'Digital';
            } else {
                $method_name = $request->withdraw_method;
            }

            Withdraw::create([
                'branch_id' => $request->branch_id ?? 1,
                'user_id' => $userInfo->id ?? null,
                'purpose' => "$method_name Withdraw",
                'withdraw_method' => $request->withdraw_method ?? null,
                'withdraw_account' => $request->withdraw_account ?? null,
                'amount' => round($request->amount, 2),
                'payble_amount' => $request->amount,
                'status' => 0
            ]);
            
            return response()->json(['status' => true, 'action' => 'success', 'message' => 'Successfully submitted withdrawn request!.']);
            
        } else {
            return "Access Denied";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess any user double-click "Submit"
So 2 receipt requests arrived, each one performed a code level check and did not see that there was an execution of another query

I have not seen use of the table lock or [transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions).

```
DB::beginTransaction();
check_if_data_already_exist();
add_data();
DB::commit();
```

This solution will greatly slow down the performance of your system.

The simplest solution is the option for each user to send one request at a given moment.

There are quite a few implementations of this problem.
In order to offer possible solutions we will need to get more information:
Is it possible to use the session?
Can the queue be used to enter the queries?
Maybe each user contains one row in the database and you can simply create a unique key at the database level

Comment: If a user double clicks the submit button he will be validated as `if (count($checkPendingRequest) > 0) {
                return response()->json(['status' => false, 'action' => 'already_pending_one', 'message' => 'Already have a pending request!.']);
            }` so it is not possible with http request

Comment: I even tried with loop, but it returns validation error after 1st insert as expected

Comment: @MVP, 
Validation is not good enough. Could be a situation where 2 requests came in at the same time, the code line Withdraw :: create still not run

Comment: there is no unique key in this table and the relation is one to many with user table, It is a rest api built with laravel, I never used queue to enter the query

Comment: yes there is my point, before inserting a row, the 2nd request was validated, how to handle this?

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote.
Option 1 is to use transactions.
Another option, is to lock the use with the help of a session.
You can read more here:
http://asteriskpound.com/2018/03/05/mutex-use-it.html

***
I would appreciate it if you could mark such a resolved question.

Comment: I used transaction for multiple table insert, Can you explain what is the benefit of checking duplicate record inside transaction, and how it will solve this problem